# Show that $k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2) \simeq k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, power-series

I have to show that $$k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^2) \simeq k[[x,y]]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$$ where $k[[x,y]]$ is the ring of formal series in $x,y$ over an algebraically closed field $k$.

I have the hint that the map $y \to y, x \to xp(x)$ suffices where $p(x) = \sqrt{1+x} = \sum_{i=0}^\infty {{1 \over 2} \choose i}x^i$.

The part that I don't understand i how is this map surjective? It'll be enough to show that the image contains $x$ or $p(x)$. But I'm unable to show either of those. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: An isomorphism is, by definition, a homomorphism that has an inverse. So construct an inverse map. For this you basically have to find $u \in k[[x]]$ with $u^2+u^3 = x^2$. Do you know the [implicit function theorem for formal power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3148008/)? If not, just write down what the coefficients of $u$ need to satisfy.